# Creating a view in PostgreSQL using columns in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

In PostgreSQL, I have the following table called `cap_output` with three columns:

```
 case_id  | libcap | libcap_android | 
----------+--------+-----------------
 06112301 |   72.6 |           75.6 |
```

Now I want to create a View based on the 2nd and 3rd columns in `cap_output` table. The view will have three columns. The second column `diff` will be the difference between `libcap` and `libcap_android`. The third column will be `TRUE` if the absolute value of the `diff` is less than 0.5 or `FALSE` otherwise. So I used the following statement to create the view

```
CREATE VIEW score_diff AS 
    SELECT c.case_id, 
    c.libcap - c.libcap_android AS diff, 
    (CASE WHEN abs(diff) < 0.5 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS pass
    FROM cap_output AS c;
```

But after creating this view, when I queried the view `score_diff`, I got the following result

```
 case_id  | diff | pass 
----------+------+------
 06112301 |   -3 | t
```

Obviously, the diff is -3 and it should return `FALSE (f)` in the `pass` column of the view. But it returned `TRUE (t)`. So why do I get wrong result?

Comment: generally speaking, you can't use an alias in the same field list it's being defined in. as written your view definition SHOULD have died with a syntax error.

Comment: @MarcB I executed the `CREATE` query without any syntax error message (Pg 9.4). So how can I refer the 2nd `diff` column in the `pass` column in Postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggests that `cap_output` has a column called `diff`.  As Marc points out, the view would otherwise have a syntax error.

So, just repeat the logic:

```
CREATE VIEW score_diff AS 
    SELECT c.case_id, 
           (c.libcap - c.libcap_android) AS diff, 
           (CASE WHEN abs(c.libcap - c.libcap_android) < 0.5 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS pass
    FROM cap_output AS c;
```

Comment: This is indeed the cause of the problem. I have a column `diff` in the table `cap_output` (just omitted it in my original question, thought it was irrelevant).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `diff` in select list. Also, `case` is not necessary. Try this:

```
CREATE VIEW score_diff AS 
    SELECT c.case_id, 
    c.libcap - c.libcap_android AS diff, 
    abs(c.libcap - c.libcap_android) < 0.5 AS pass
    FROM cap_output AS c;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is simpler than mine.